# Is it possible to have same routes with different show action in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I am trying to reach the following url in my rails app:

```
example.com/user12 # It should show user#show
exmple.com/wordpress # It should show category#show
```

**My solution:** (it does not work)

In the `routes.rb` I have added `:path => ''` to both `categories and users` in order to remove the controllers' name from the url.

```
resources :categories, :path => ''
resources :users, :path => ''
```

When I run `rake routes`, I have the following urls"

```
category GET    /:id(.:format)   category#show
account GET    /:id(.:format)    accounts#show
```

So I assumed that It should be working correctly, but surely not. It only works for category names and for usernames it shows `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`.

I know, my solution is wrong because I am confusing rails route system and because the `resources :categories` has more priority over `resources :users`, the category show page works fine.

**So Is there any solution to solve an issue like this?**

Comment: No, directly is not possible for work same routes with different controller,
you need to separate the routes such like "get '/category/:name' => 'category#show'" && "get '/account/:name' => 'account#show'"

Comment: Yes, if I remove the `:path => ''`, the routes will be the defult with controller name.

Comment: yes but its always go to first matching routes. and by default it match with Id, and you are trying with name. Thats why it show error as 'ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found the solution with `constraints` option. This option accepts regular expressions.

```
resources :categories, :path => '', constraints: { id: /wordpress|php/ }
```

Every category should be added manually in this way OR (I am not sure) maybe there is a way to list all categories from database automatically.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing that is to override the default rails routes, to do that remove the `resources`

I tested and this works

```
SampleRails4::Application.routes.draw do
  get '/user12', to: 'users#show' #=> users/show  
  get '/wordpress', to: 'category#show' #=> assuming u have a controller and action 
end
```

however then you have to update the rest of your code, Ex: `users/show` might be expecting the user id as a `param` [read more](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) about rails routing